# Trigger close the pg Admin?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, pgadmin

I created a trigger **fk_pay_trigger on INSERT**

```
CREATE TRIGGER fk_pay_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON fk_payment_temp
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE add_insert_trigger_fk()
```

and function attach is:

```
-- Function: add_insert_trigger_fk()

-- DROP FUNCTION add_insert_trigger_fk();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_insert_trigger_fk()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
Declare 

begin 
    if (TG_TABLE_NAME = 'fk_payment_temp') then 
        if (TG_OP = 'INSERT') then
            Insert into fk_payment_temp_backup values(now(),NEW.settlement_ref_no, NEW.order_type, NEW.fulfilment_type, NEW.seller_sku, NEW.wsn, 
                   NEW.order_id, NEW.order_item_id, NEW.order_date, NEW.dispatch_date, NEW.delivery_date, 
                   NEW.cancellation_date, NEW.settlement_date, NEW.order_status, NEW.quantity, NEW.order_item_value, 
                   NEW.sale_transaction_amount, NEW.discount_transaction_amount, NEW.refund, 
                   NEW.protection_fund, NEW.total_marketplace_fee, NEW.service_tax, NEW.settlement_value, 
                   NEW.commission_rate, NEW.commission, NEW.payment_rate, NEW.payment_fee, NEW.fee_discount, 
                   NEW.cancellation_fee, NEW.fixed_fee, NEW.emi_fee, NEW.total_weight, NEW.shipping_fee, 
                   NEW.reverse_shipping_fee, NEW.shipping_zone, NEW.token_of_apology, NEW.pick_and_pack_fee, 
                   NEW.storage_fee, NEW.removal_fee, NEW.invoice_id, NEW.invoice_date, NEW.invoice_amount, 
                   NEW.sub_category, NEW.total_offer_amount, NEW.my_offer_share, NEW.flipkart_offer_share);
            return NEW;
        END if;
    End if ;
    return null;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Its working fine. but the problem is :

when trigger perform . PG admin Shut down automatically .

I dont know what happen . Is there is any problem in my code or any problem ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "*pgAdmin shut down automatically*"?

Comment: Pg admin is open. and the insert command run through the program. after that pgadmin is close itself.

Comment: This sounds like abnormal behavior.  What OS and PgAdmin version?

Comment: Show your `INSERT` and confirm that it does work without the trigger.

Comment: @Hambone OS :- ubuntu 14.0   and PgAdmin:- 1.20

Comment: @JakubKania My Insert Query using Python Program. and Its work correctly i tested it several time before applying  trigger.

Comment: @ShubhamBatra So you're saying that when you run a python program your PgAdmin closes? And you didn't show the INSERT, nor did you describe what exactly is happening. Noone can help you if you don't tell us what are you doing.

Comment: Does it shut down every single time or sporatically?  Is PgAdmin running on the same box as the PostgreSQL server?  It's a total shot in the dark, but have you tried installing 1.18 and seeing if it still occurs on it?

Comment: @Hambone        **->** shut down as i perform insert program .                         **->** PgAdmin and Postgresql server both is on same box (localhost)                **->** Now I will try with Installing PGAdmin on VMware